# Function template with reference template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

There is this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<const double& f>
void fun5(){
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
} 

int main() 
{ 
    const double dddd = 5.0;
    fun5<dddd>();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler error during compilation:

```
$ g++ klasa.cpp -o klasa
klasa.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
klasa.cpp:11:10: error: ‘dddd’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
klasa.cpp:11:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘fun5()’
klasa.cpp:11:16: note: candidate is:
klasa.cpp:4:6: note: template<const double& f> void fun5()
```

Why placing 'dddd' as template parameter doesn't work and what should be done to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

References and pointers for template arguments must have external linkage (or internal linkage, for C++11, but static storage duration is required). So if you have to use `dddd` as a template argument, you need to move it to global scope and make it `extern`:

```
extern const double dddd = 5.0;
int main()
{
    fun5<dddd>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to make it `extern`; as you say, it can have internal linkage.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Theoretically, yes, but both gcc and clang rejects that if `extern` is omitted :(.

Comment: g++ 6.1 accepts 'extern const double dddd = 5.0;' or just 'double dddd = 5.0;', however 'const double dddd = 5.0;' is not accepted (all of them defined in global area over function main)

Comment: adding to above: maybe because const double dddd = 5.0 can be inlined so that compiler places value 5.0 where dddd variable occurrs and it is not really represented in memory, I don't know, just thinking

Comment: Since C++17, the linkage restriction is removed, while static storage duration is still required.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably misunderstood the purpose of templates. Template arguments (the things between angle brackets) should either be types, or integers (though some implementation allows floating-point types).

In your case, it would be better to declare `fun5` as `void fun5(double& f)`, and call it like `fun5(dddd)`.

Comment: it's not practical case, I just want to see how function templates work with references as template parameters.