# Why can't I have a reference to local variable as a non-type template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I don't understand why this works:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int& obj>
void foo() { obj = 42; }

int i;

int main()
{
    foo<i>();
    std::cout << i;
}
```

and that doesn't:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int& obj>
void foo() { obj = 42; }

int main()
{
    int i;
    foo<i>();
    std::cout << i;
}
//error: the value of 'i' is not usable in a constant expression
```

Comment: why is my question downvoted. It is clear and concise and an actual C++ question

Comment: The compiler cannot realistically know where the stack frame of the containing function will be.  It might even be different across multiple function calls.  (Although, in this example, re-entering `main` would be UB anyway but it could be any function.)

Comment: Sorry, a better duplicate would have been: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218615/function-template-with-reference-template-parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address of the local variable is a run-time feature, the address of the static variable is a compile time feature.