# external linkage template object eror

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

below code compiles fine in clang++ -std=c++1y where as same give error in g++ -std=c++1y

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Demo {
public: 
    Demo(){}
};


template <Demo  const &ref>
void fun(){}


Demo g;
const Demo g_c;

int main(){
    fun<g>();
    fun<g_c>();

};
```

below error in g++

```
error: the value of ‘g_c’ is not usable in a constant expression
  fun<g_c>();
      ^
error: ‘g_c’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘const Demo&’     because object ‘g_c’ has not external linkage
  fun<g_c>();
       ^
```

const Demo g_c;
has internal linkage right ?? does it mean g++ has bug or something wrong in my analysis ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function template with reference template parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218615/function-template-with-reference-template-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> const Demo g_c;
>   has internal linkage right ??

Correct. A (non-local) `const`-qualified object has internal linkage unless the declaration or an earlier declaration explicitly gives it external linkage.

> does it mean g++ has bug or something wrong in my analysis ??

Your analysis is certainly wrong. GCC's error is telling you that references to objects cannot be used as template arguments unless those objects have external linkage. Your object doesn't have external linkage, so GCC's error does match what it is actually checking.

But it does also mean that g++ has a bug. The rule it enforces was from C++03. C++11 relaxes the rule and your code is now valid. This is [a known bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR52036).

You can work around it by giving your object external linkage:

```
extern const Demo g_c;
const Demo g_c;
```

or

```
extern const Demo g_c {};
```